# Question related to back button

Tags: iphone

I  want to  show  the  `UIBarButtonItem`  and  `UINavigationItem`  through code in the method `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to give a little more details, but probably you mean something like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back" 
                                         style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                        target: self 
                                        action: @selector(backAction)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;
[btn release];
```